# Is this the correct syntax for an array of pointers to size-3 character arrays?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my own version of an "Autocorrect" program that checks for words that are similar to a given word. To accomplish this, I need to look at distances between letters on a standard keyboard, so that I have a metric for how "close" a word is to another word.

In my program I've started to write an array

```
const char[3]* KEY_DISTS[] = { "aa0", "ab5", "ba5", "ac3", "ca3", "ad2", "da2" ,... };
```

which is supposed to mean "The distance between 'a' and 'a' is 0, the distance between 'a' and 'b' is 5, the distance between 'b' and 'a' is 5, " etcetera.

That information I will next put in a map that maps pairs of characters to integers, but I'm wondering whether it's written correctly so far and whether you have any suggestions for me.

```
const char[3]* KEY_DISTS[]
```

should mean "A constant array of pointers to character arrays of size 3", right?

Comment: Why do you need that array in the first place? Why not directly initialize the map? Or why not use a file to read from? Also note that the distances depend on the keyboard layout...

Comment: It sounds like you actually want "an array of size-3 arrays of chars"...  In other words, `const char KEY_DISTS[][3] = ...`.

Comment: Also note that a string literal is an array of const chars but one element more than the number of letters (since there is a null terminating char at the end). So you'd need arrays of size 4 each.

Comment: Yea, I think I'm just gonna write these in a text file. It's gonna take forever lol. 26 x 26 = 676 pairwise distances.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration matching the title would be:

```
const char (*arr[])[4] = { &"aa0" };
```

Note that `"arr"` is an array of four chars (it includes terminating `'\0'`) and that you need to take the address of string literal (which are lvalues and have static storage duration, so this is fine).

Sounds like you could have a 2D array instead:

```
const char arr[][4] = { "aa0" };
```